# SQLite, 'SELECT 0 OR NULL' vs 'SELECT 1 OR NULL', strange result

Tags: sqlite

I've come across a very strange in behavior in SQLite with boolean expressions, or whatever is actually going on.

```
SELECT 1 OR NULL
-- Result: 1

SELECT 0 OR NULL
-- Result: NULL
```

It even interprets strings and performs the same strange evaluation:

```
SELECT '789abc' OR NULL
-- Result: 1

SELECT '000abc' OR NULL
-- Result: NULL
```

The order of the expression does not matter and if you add more similar expressions and operators it still evaluates the same.
Can someone please explain the logic behind this strange asymmetry? What's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: NULL is an unknown value. You can't select it directly, or do comparisons against it. `SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE myCol = NULL` returns no rows, even if every row contains null in that column. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. Any direct comparison against NULL is NULL, because you can't compare things against something unknown. How can you tell if something that is entirely unknown is equal to, less than, or more than anything else (including another unknown value)? This is one of the very first things that you learn from any decent SQL book or tutorial or class.

Comment: @KenWhite I have 20+ years of experience of working with SQL in different environments, but thank you for explaining NULL to me. For your future invaluable contributions to this forum I recommend you take the time to understand the question before bestowing your mystic knowledge unto us mere mortals.

Comment: Excuse me for responding based on the lack of knowledge shown in your question when you wrote `OR NULL`, which is clearly the use of NULL by someone who is not familiar with how it should be handled. Don't blame me for the ignorance of the topic shown by the code you yourself posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses type coercion, interpreting non-zero numbers as `true`, and zero or empty strings as `false`. But `NULL` does not mean `false`. It means `unknown` value, hence:

- `1 OR NULL` returns `1` because `1` is `true`, and `true OR anything` is **always** `true`, regardless of 2nd value (in fact boolean optimization usually does not even bother the 2nd argument in such case, so unknown or not it simply does not matter at all).
- `0 OR NULL` returns `NULL` because `0` is `false`, and `false OR NULL` means `false OR unknown` so the result is unknown. In this case `unknown` matters as it would affect the result if known.

The next case look bit more convoluted but are resolved using the same rules as above. The `'789abc' OR NULL` returns `1` because the first argument will be converted to numeric value first. The tricky part is that it will not be interpreted as hex string but instead only starting digits will remain (`789`) and anything starting from next non-digit character to the **end of the string** will be dropped:

```
> SELECT '100abc23' + 0;
100
> SELECT '00abc23' + 0;
0
```

So  `789abc` is `789` which is non-zero when converted and that means value is treated as `true`, so again `true OR anything` is `true`.

The last one is similar: The `000abc` string again will be converted and again SQLite will drop anything starting at first non-digit character to the end of the string. So your`000abc` becomes `000` and that converts to `0` which is considered `false`. Therefore `false OR NULL` is `false OR unknown` so the result is unknown.

If these numeric strings are in fact hex and you want SQLite to treat them as such, you need to use `hex()` function:

```
> SELECT hex('000abc') OR NULL;
1
```

Answer (score -1):

Well it is kinda catchy...
First I believe that the value NULL is often misunderstood. It does not mean 'nothing' but it means 'something not known'. Therefore it can be interpreted as a 'truthy' value.

SELECT 0 OR NULL
-- Result: NULL

It return null because 0 is definitely a falsy value, therefore the OR operator return the first 'truthy' value it finds. So it will not return 0, it might return the second value, which is 'NULL' in this case.

Another catchy thing... the OR operator can render 3 different results. true, false and unknown.
2 + unknown = unknow, right?
unknown multiplied by 3 = unknown...

So between 0 OR NULL, it will not render 'false' (or 0) as a result, but rather NULL.

Well, taking that NULL should not be considered as 'NOTHING' then it is a truthy value, it is an unknown value.

The result should be NULL, all right.

SELECT '000abc' OR NULL
-- Result: NULL

Now it comes the most catchy part of the answer...
SQLite will compare both values but first it must convert both values in a common type. It is hard to compare oranges and apples, so it tries to convert both values to a number.

000abc can be converted to 0, a number, but we have already seen that between 0 and NULL, SQLite takes the NULL as an answer.

Comment: `NULL` values are _not_ truth-y values. The SQL standard defines (somewhat ambiguous at times) how `NULL`s are to be handled, for which SQLite has [clear documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html)